# Dropbox Webhooks contains no post data

Tags: php, dropbox, webhooks

I'm trying to track my users' file changes with Dropbox's Webhooks interface. I expected the call to include POST data, but there doesn't seem to be POST data (or GET data, for that matter). Here is my PHP code, where the `if` part is for Dropbox to validate the webhook, and the `else` part saves the `$_POST` and `$_GET` variables to a file.

```
<?php
if( isset( $_GET['challenge'] ) ) {
    echo $_GET['challenge'];
} else {
    $output = print_r($_POST, true);
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND );
    $output = print_r($_GET, true);
    file_put_contents('file.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND );
}
?>
```

After a short while, `file.txt` fills up with this:

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013756/1447002) to a related question, you need to get the JSON data like this:

```
$output = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Or, since it's JSON:

```
$output = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
```